# How can I make NetBeans not stop on the first line with xdebug?

Tags: netbeans, xdebug, netbeans6.5

I'm using NetBeans 6.5 for developing PHP and I have xdebug setup. Is there a way I can tell it not to stop on the first line of the file on every request? JIT mode won't fix this because I don't want it to stop on every exception that I catch.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I just found my answer, you go to Tools > Options > PHP (section) and there is a checkbox for "stop at the first line"

Comment: Finally - it only just occurred to me this might be optional. Saving me bags of time now!

Comment: probably obvious, but is under the "Debug" page of PHP section

Answer (score 9):

For Mac users, you go to the Netbeans > Preferences... and find it under the PHP section

Answer (score 1):

Tools -> Options -> Php -> Debugging -> Uncheck "Stop at first line" -> Apply -> OK.

[image]

[image]